# Using Two GridViews in Two Separate UpdatePanels

Tags: asp.net, gridview, updatepanel

I have two `<asp:UpdatePanel>` containing one `<asp:GridView>` each. What `<Trigger>` should I use in my second `<asp:UpdatePanel>` so that second `<asp:GridView>` would load data based on the SelectedIndex of the `<asp:GridView>` in my first `<asp:UpdatePanel>`?

Just a general idea of the operation will do. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="GridView1" EventName="SelectedIndexChanged" />
```

Comment: Thanks, I think I just referenced the wrong control in my previous attempt.